# User control file isn't loaded in asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui, ascx

I have a view with the following Kendo component :

```
<% Html.Kendo()
       .TabStrip()
       .Name("tabstrip")
       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "vertical-align:text-top;" })
       .Items(tabstrip =>
       {                           
              tabstrip.Add()
                      .Text("Véhicules en attente")
                      .Selected(true)
                      .Content("<div id='DivVehiculesEnAttente'>  </div>");                          
              tabstrip.Add()
                      .Text("Véhicules repartis")       
                      .Content("<div id='DivVehiculesRepartis'>  </div>");                           

       })
       .Animation(animation =>
       {
                  animation.Enable(true);
                  animation.Open(config =>
                  {
                                 config.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
                                 config.Duration(AnimationDuration.Fast);
                  });
       })
       .Render();
%>
```

The following Ajax success function return it content to the "DivVehiculesEnAttente" div :

```
function UpdateVehiculesEnAttente()
{
    var value = "02/17/2016";   
    $(document).ready($.ajax({
        url: 'Entrees_Sorties/Get_Vehicules_EnAttente',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'date' : value},

        success: function (retour) {
            $("#DivVehiculesEnAttente").html(retour);
            console.log("update attente success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            montrerNotificationNoConnexion();
            console.log("xhr :");
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("status :");
            console.log(status);
            console.log("error :");
            console.log(error);
        }
    }));
return false;    
}
```

Here is my Controller method "Get_Vehicule_EnAttente" and the method that is launched with it.

```
public ActionResult Get_Vehicules_EnAttente([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string date)
    {
        try
        {
            List<List<Vehicule>> Data = new List<List<Vehicule>>();

            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
            Data.Add(Models.Vehicule.Get_Vehicules_EnAttente_ByDate(dt, true));
            return PartialView("VehiculesEnAttente", Data);               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WorkflowWCF.Log.enregistrer_erreur(new Exception("Une erreur est survenue lors de la récupération des véhicules planifiés", e));
            return Json(new List<Vehicule>().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure the following method work because it worked on a previous version.

```
    internal static List<Vehicule> Get_Vehicules_EnAttente_ByDate(DateTime date, bool allowOccurences)
    {
        try
        {
        // Récupération des véhicules avec une planif ET en attente
        List<Models.Vehicule> listeVehicules = new List<Models.Vehicule>();
        List<WorkflowWCF.Vehicule_Quai> liste = My_service.Get_Vehicules_AvecPlanif_ByEtatDate(
            WorkflowWCF.Vehicule.EtatWF.EnAttente, date, date, allowOccurences);

        // Pour chacun de ces véhicules...
        foreach (WorkflowWCF.Vehicule_Quai vQ in liste)
        {
            // Création de l'objet à afficher dans la vue
            Vehicule vPlanifie = ToVueModel(vQ);

            // s'il est de type récurrent 
            if (vQ.IsRecurrent())
            {
                // Le workflow n'a pas encore démarré, ce véhicule n'est pas arrivé.
                vPlanifie.WorkflowID = Guid.Empty;
                // pour retrouver la planification du véhicule récurrent
                vPlanifie.WorkflowID_VehiculePlanifie = vQ.WorkflowID;
            }
            else
            {
                // WorkflowID
                vPlanifie.WorkflowID = vQ.WorkflowID;
                vPlanifie.WorkflowID_VehiculePlanifie = Guid.Empty;
            }

            // Ajout dans le liste
            listeVehicules.Add(vPlanifie);
            // }                
        }
            return listeVehicules;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Une erreur est survenue dans la fonction Get_Vehicules_EnAttente_ByDate", ex);                
        }

    }
```

And finally, here is the code of my UserControl file :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<IntranetMVC.Models.Vehicule>>>" %>

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Entrees_Sorties/VehiculesEnAttente.js") %>"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Entrees_Sorties/Entrees_Sorties.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
     $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
         value: new Date(),
         change: UpdateVehiculesEnAttente
     });    
</script>
<!-- Description : Vue partielle affichant la grille des vehicules attendus sur le site -->
<div class="tabKendo" style="text-align:center" align="center">
     <!-- GRILLES DE DONNES -->

     <% Html.Kendo()
            .Grid<IntranetMVC.Models.Vehicule>()
            .Name("Gd_Today")
            .BindTo(Model[0])
            .Events(e => e
            .Change("OnVehiculeArrive_va"))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                     columns.Bound(c => c.sHeurePrevue).Width(100).Title("Heure");
                     columns.Bound(c => c.NomTransporteurPrevu)
                            .Width(200)
                            .ClientTemplate("#= data.NomTransporteur.substring(0,14) #")
                            .Title("Transporteur");                        
            })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 464px; width: 300px; margin:5px; font-size:130%" })
            .Sortable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                       .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                       .Ajax()
                       .ServerOperation(false)
                       .Sort(sort => sort.Add("sHeurePrevue").Ascending()))
            .Render();                                                        
     %>
</div>
```

And I can't load this page. My function is load, I got the message "update attente success" from my ajax request. I tried to add a console.log("test") in my User Control file to test if it's launched but I got nothing. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: How is your view with the tab strip that contains the content div displayed? Is that logic in the `OnVehiculeArrive_va()` function? If the html of the tab strip is not rendered in the DOM tree before `UpdateVehiculesEnAttente()` fires, you will not see anything because the div does not exist.

Comment: @Brett The rest of the view appears correctly. The OnVehiculeArrive_va() is called when clicking on one of the element in the Kendo table. I tried the app with firebug on, it seems that "retour" in the ajax request is empty.

Comment: I see. Make sure `Entrees_Sorties/Get_Vehicules_EnAttente` is the correct URL and it returns data.

Comment: I'm sure it's the correct URL because it worked before some changement. I tried to use the debugger to see what I have in my controller method. The problem is that I use Telerik component that are not allowed in IE, and Visual can't launch javascript file except in IE. I will edit my post and add my controller method.